# How do I resolve the following error during "configure: error: XSLT configuration could not be found"

Tags: compiling

When compiling Icecast 2, I get this error when I run `autogen.sh`:

```
$ autogen.sh
... stuff ommitted
configure: error: XSLT configuration could not be found
```

What is the reason for it, and how do I fix it?

Answer (score 24, accepted):

You're missing some XML libraries. Try installing `libxml2-dev`. On Ubuntu or Debian, use

```
sudo apt-get install libxslt-dev
```

On Fedora or such it would be

```
yum install libxslt-devel
```